# R Import Large dataset with all columns as text

Tags: r, etl

I am trying to import a large data set using the R package `VROOM`. It has 72 columns, I am unsure on how to explicitly set all columns as text during the import.

I've tried the following code but it does not work.
`b <- vroom(data, rep("c",72))`

Comment: I guess you need the `file` argument insted of 'data'.  and perhaps you want `vroom(filepath, col_types = as.list(rep(col_character(), 72)))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun 
Final Workable code is below
`vroom(filepath, col_types = as.list(rep("c", 72)))`